# Magento2 - Remove Extra space from Shopping cart image

Tags: magento2, cart, shopping-cart

Here I am facing a UI issue but don't know how to solve it.

In My shopping cart page my product image is getting extra space i dont know from where it is coming.

[image]

Comment: you need to remove the tag from CSS if you do not know the file.

Comment: this issue is another div is spacing Please remove the blank div class and solve this issues